# How to pick only specific selector declaration's css

Tags: php, css, joomla, custom-component

I am basically a `PHP` developer but I came across a problem that in Joomla component development I have to install my own component independently in any Joomla website which I have done successfully. The problem is that when I run my component on random Joomla website it also picks the css of the parent template which I don't want it to do. For example, I have a bootstrap model in my component with class `model` and the template has some css applying (for example `background-color: white`) on the same class `model` then there shows a white background on the model which is really awkward and doesn't make any sense.

```
.model{ // I want this to be picked 
 font-size: 15px;
}


.model{ // I don't want this to be picked 
 background-color: white;
}
```

So is this possible to pick only the desired selector's css which is declared multiple times?

Comment: No. You need to override those rules. May be something like `.your-component .model { background-color: transparent; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you have developed your own Joomla component and your class names are clashing with other classes, then the simplest / most sensible course of action would be to declare unique class names that avoid collisions.

`zain_model` should be sufficiently unique forever.  Or prefix however you like.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which template my client will install

Comment: If you write a sufficiently unique class name and write the css styling for it, then it won't matter.

Comment: Hmm, but what about standard bootstrap classes?

Comment: You want to style only the elements associated with YOUR component.  You have complete control of the class declarations in the scripts that you write.  If you want bootstrap's default behaviors to work on some elements, leave the original class attribute in place.  If you want additional styling, add an additional value (`zain_` prefixed) to the class declaration.  If you don't want specific styling, remove the original class.  If you want to negate or override a style, then make a specific declaration to counteract the specific style.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, any element declared within its parent element WILL inherit all of the css attributes of the parent class. So if you would like to remove the white background in that child element, you could

a) declare another css class for the child element that sets the background of the child element to something else (in you case make a “.submodel” class that sets background to transparent or another colour, and also include your font size to what you desire
b)declare an ID “#submodel” and do the declarations described in a)
c) if this child is a generic p (paragraph) or h (header) element, you can specify that section’s class as:

```
.model p {
     -set background to new colour
     -set font size
 }
```

In css, element styles are always inherited from parent elements, so when designing styles beets you should keep in mind how specific your classes get as it will reduce flexibility in the long run, just as a side note

More information on css inheritance can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate your effort but that's not the solution. I have independent CSS of my Joomla component which running perfectly independently but when I use any template it inherits the template's css which creates the problem and every template has a different css (If I switch to different templates). So I can't change the css of my component manually each time

Answer (score 0):

override with css

```
.model{
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```